# Load registry key error

Tags: c++, registry

I try several codes for load a string key from registry and after testing them I found this one that I write down. but a very confusing thing is that this code work for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/HARDWARE keys but don't work for SOFTWARE one's. I don't know what I ignore?

```
char rgValue [512];
char fnlRes [512];
DWORD size1;
DWORD Type;
HKEY hKey = 0;
char buf[512] = {0};
DWORD dwType = 0;
DWORD dwBufSize = sizeof(buf);

if(  RegOpenKeyEx( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, TEXT("SOFTWARE\\SCADE\\HMI"), 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hKey ) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    dwType = REG_DWORD;
    if( RegQueryValueEx( hKey, TEXT("test"), 0, &dwType, (LPBYTE)buf, &dwBufSize ) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        cout << "key value is '" << buf << "'\n";
    }
    else
        cout << "can not query for key value\n";
    RegCloseKey(hKey);
}
else
    cout << "Can not open key\n";
```

Comment: Call `GetLastError` and update your post with the result.

Comment: @RichardCritten I don't familiar with  GetLastError but I insert it in my code and it returned 0 value. In my main code after opening regKey successfully RegQueryValueEx face with error and debugger jump to "can not query for key value" line

Comment: Have just read the docs for `RegQueryValueEx` read about the return result it does not return a boolean value: see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724911(v=vs.85).aspx  See also the sample in the link

Comment: @RichardCritten Registry functions don't use `GetLastError()`, they return error codes directly.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be reading a `DWORD` value from the Registry, but you are trying to output it to the console as if it were a null-terminated string instead. To read a `DWORD`, change your buffer variable from `char[]` to `DWORD`, and use the `&` operator to pass its address to `RegQueryValueEx()`, eg:

```
HKEY hKey = 0;
DWORD dwValue = 0;
DWORD dwType = 0;
DWORD dwBufSize = sizeof(dwValue);
LONG lRes;

lRes = RegOpenKeyEx( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, TEXT("SOFTWARE\\SCADE\\HMI"), 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hKey );
if (lRes == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    lRes = RegQueryValueEx( hKey, TEXT("test"), 0, &dwType, (LPBYTE)&dwValue, &dwBufSize );
    if (lRes == ERROR_SUCCESS) 
    {
        if (dwType == REG_DWORD)
            cout << "key value is " << dwValue << endl;
        else
            cout << "key value is not a DWORD" << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "can not query for key value. Error: " << lRes << endl;
    RegCloseKey(hKey);
}
else
   cout << "Can not open key. Error: " << lRes << endl;
```

Comment: thank you for your answe. I try your code for for some reg keys but none of them loaded. lRes return 2 for some keys and 234 for some others. I check my registry permissions and there is not any problem.I run my program as admin but it does not work yet!!!

Comment: what is confusing in that I can open some keys from some roots but I can't  read my own key that created in a special root!!!

Comment: Error 2 is `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`, and error 234 is `ERROR_MORE_DATA`. Both are explained in the [`RegQueryValueEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724911.aspx) documentation: "*If `lpValueName` specifies a value that is not in the registry, the function returns `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`... If the buffer specified by `lpData` parameter is not large enough to hold the data, the function returns `ERROR_MORE_DATA` and stores the required buffer size in the variable pointed to by `lpcbData`. In this case, the contents of the `lpData` buffer are undefined.*"